# Lots of functions that do the same thing - what is a good design pattern for DRY?

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, dry

tI am looking to refactor a piece of code that provides a programmatic interface to the stored procedures of a database. However, I find myself in the postion of having to create potentially hundreds of functions that do the same thing with a few different configurations.

1. The stored procedure the function uses
2. A mapping to a configuration object that provides args and validation params for that particular stored procedure

As an example:

```
getCountries = function(params){
   var options = { statement : 'proc_1'}
   return run_request(options, params, mappings.select.countries)
}

getStates = function(params){
   var options = { statement : 'proc_2'}
   return run_request(options, params, mappings.select.states)
}
```

Naturally, this does not feel very DRY and gets problematic when there are a lot of these.

I'm curious as to the different ways that I can handle this case, and what the 'best practices' are.

I thought about having one large config and a director function that, given string parameters will go get the proper stored procedure and its configuration. e.g :

```
get('countries', params)
```

But I'm not sure about this, as the strings may seem a bit arbitrary in some cases.

Another thing I thought about was also having one huge config that just auto generates the functions at runtime. This seems more preferable, but I'm still stuck with a really big file that may be a pain to maintain, though it seems to follow DRY better than my current implementation.

Thoughts? Are there any particular design patterns I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not confuse form with function.**

You have two examples of code with the same "*shape*", but which perform different *functions*.  That's OK.  DRY is about not doing the same *function* multiple times (and, inevitably, multiple ways).